# how to run map reduce on a mongo collection which is having growing array field

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mapreduce

We running map reduce on 10 fields in a collection. In those 10 fields we have a growing array field. It was fine until the array size limited.

But when the array size became 100 and above, the mapreduce has stopped working. It is giving some exception saying array size is bigger.

```
Actual scenario : 
MyDocument{
_I'd : 1234,
Name : some,
Email : somex@somedomain.com,
Age : 20,
Gender : female,
City : some city
Interests[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
Status : active}
```

With mapreduce we are able to get all counts with all permutations and combinations.

But after interest array field becomes big, the mapreduce is not running.

If we remove that field and maintain it seperatly, we may not get counts based on gender age and interest.

Can any one suggest a better approach to this?

Comment: You need to "explain" the problem more clearly if you want an answer here. If you want a better way, then show the expected result from some input documents ( presumably more than one if you are using map reduce ) and that gives people something they can understand to suggest an alternate process.

Comment: 1. Due to Interests field (Interests[1,2,3,4,5,6,7....120]) mapreduce  job is not executing.

Comment: Well you are not showing us your code here are you? Without that we cannot see what the problem is.

Comment: The following exception is occuring when we run the mapreduce job. 
Exc in MongoMapReduce : { "serverUsed" : "IP:PORT" , "errmsg" : "exception: Btree::insert: key too large to index, failing db.collection_5_inc.$_temp_0 1651 { : { country: null, state: null, city: null, Interests: [ 3.0, 79.0, 93.0, 7.0, 72.0, ......... ] } }" , "code" : 17280 , "ok" : 0.0}